# JavaScript: How do I print multiple script tags in a loop?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

i'm new to javascript: learning by doing ..  i want to do something like

```
for(var_terms as variable_term){
  print(  <script 
            type="text/javascript" 
            src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=variable_term&callback=showMyVideos">
        </script> )

}
```

on the client side..i basically want `showMyVideos` applied to multiple search queries from an array/database/file and not just one predetermined query.

Thanks

Comment: You can use the DOM API to create and insert `script` elements.

Answer (score 1):

please take a look at http://jquery.com/ it will help you with this, there is extensive documentation on the jquery page

Comment: I think it's more important to know the JS syntax before diving into jQuery.