# Why does this javascript not print out a series of script elements?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: How do I print multiple script tags in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755908/javascript-how-do-i-print-multiple-script-tags-in-a-loop)

Im trying to print these elements from an array but i get a blank screen

```
<div id="playerContainer" style="width: 20em; height: 180px; float: left;">
    <object id="player"></object>
</div>
<div id="videos2"></div><script type = "text/javascript">
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    document.write("<script 
        type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=arr["+i+"] &max-results=8&orderby=relevance&alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showMyVideos2">
    </script>");

}
</script>
```

Comment: How is your `arr` array defined? Could you provide that piece of code?

Comment: You're using unescaped double quotes inside double quote limited string. Keep the JavaScript error console open, the error messages are displayed there.

Comment: what is in your arr variable?
The i variable only contains a counterm maybe you should try to use arr[i] instead

Comment: you already asked this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755908/javascript-how-do-i-print-multiple-script-tags-in-a-loop/9756123#9756123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My version - assuming arr contains stuff you want to send to the q=

```
<div id="playerContainer" style="width: 20em; height: 180px; float: left;">
    <object id="player"></object>
</div>
<div id="videos2"></div><script type="text/javascript">
var text ="";
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  text += '<script type="text/javascript" '+
  'src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='+arr[i]+
  '&max-results=8&orderby=relevance&alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showMyVideos2">'+
  '<\/script>';
}
document.write(text);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="videos2"></div><script type = "text/javascript">
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=' + arr[i] + '&max-results=8&orderby=relevance&alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showMyVideos2"></scr' + 'ipt>');    
}
</script>
```

- Browser will see the  tag in the script and close it
- You had problems with quotes
- You have a problem with the arr[i] call

Comment: `.write("<scr" + "ipt` ... ?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        document.write('< ' + 'script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='+arr[i]+'&max-results=8&orderby=relevance&alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showMyVideos2"><' + '/script>');

    }
</script>
```

You need to escape your quotes, split the script tags so it don't get parsed as tags, and change your i variable with arr[i] in the loop

Comment: You mixed up with the  quotes as well... =)

Comment: oops, I corrected the quotes, thanx for pointing that out @gdoron

Comment: It doesn't look fixed to me. **:(**

Comment: @gdoron I moved everything to one line, so now it should look correct